# Many-To-One Association in Spring JPA does not update related entity

Tags: java, eclipselink, many-to-one, spring-repositories, spring-boot-jpa

I have a problem inserting JPA entites in the DB using a many-to-one association.

I'm using:

- Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE
- Ecliselink 2.7.4.RC2 (org.eclipse.persistence.jpa)
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

I'm using Spring's repository where I only have a save method and no insert, merge or update methods.

I use an entity `DbWatchlist` which has a many-to-one association to another entity `DbWatchlistProvider`.

If I create a new `DBWatchlist` with the fields for `DbWatchlistProvider` filled everything works fine. Also if I change an existing `DbWatchlist` and also here the fields for `DbWatchlistProvider` and do a save everything works.

But if I try to create a new `DbWatchlist` with an existing `DbWatchlistProvider` JPA always tries to INSERT a new record for `DbWatchlistProvider`.

I tried to read the `DbWatchlistProvider` from the database before inserting into the entity `DbWatchlist` and after that do a save, but also here an INSERT is done. This results in a exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10144 table: WATCHLISTPROVIDER
Error Code: -104
Call: INSERT INTO WatchlistProvider (Key, Description, Id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]
```

My code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TableName.WATCHLIST, uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {ColumnName.PROVIDER_KEY, ColumnName.ID})})
@UuidGenerator(name = KEY_GENERATOR)
public class DbWatchlist {

  @Id
  @Column(name = ColumnName.KEY, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = KEY_GENERATOR)
  public String key;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = ColumnName.PROVIDER_KEY, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  public DbWatchlistProvider watchlistProvider;

  @Column(name = ColumnName.ID, nullable = false)
  public String id;

  @Column(name = ColumnName.DESCRIPTION)
  public String description;

  @Column(name = ColumnName.LATEST_VERSION)
  public String latestVersion;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = TableName.PROVIDER, uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {ColumnName.ID})})
@UuidGenerator(name = KEY_GENERATOR)
public class DbWatchlistProvider {

  @Id
  @Column(name = ColumnName.KEY, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = KEY_GENERATOR)
  public String key;

  @Column(name = ColumnName.ID, nullable = false)
  public String id;

  @Column(name = ColumnName.DESCRIPTION)
  public String description;
}

@Repository
public interface WatchlistRepository extends CrudRepository<DbWatchlist, String> {

  boolean existsByWatchlistProviderAndId(DbWatchlistProvider provider, String id);
}
```

In my test I tried the following:

```
DbWatchlistProvider provider = new DbWatchlistProvider();
provider.id = "PROV";
provider.description = "description for provider";

DbWatchlist newRow = new DbWatchlist();
newRow.id = "ID1";
newRow.description = "description";
newRow.watchlistProvider = provider;

DbWatchlist createdRow = repository.save(newRow);

createdRow.description = "update";
createdRow.watchlistProvider.description = "also updated";
createdRow = repository.save(createdRow);

DbWatchlist createdRow2 = new DbWatchlist();
createdRow2.watchlistProvider = createdRow.watchlistProvider;
createdRow2.id = "test";
createdRow2.description = "description";

//This save is not working, but the createdRow2.watchlistProvider.key is filled
repository.save(createdRow2);
```

Till the last save everything is working without errors and like expected.
Has someone any idea what is the problem and why the `DbWatchlistProvider` is trying to be inserted and not updated?

Exception is:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10144 table: WATCHLISTPROVIDER
Error Code: -104

Call: INSERT INTO WatchlistProvider (Key, Description, Id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
bind => [3 parameters bound]

Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

Query: InsertObjectQuery

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10144 table: WATCHLISTPROVIDER

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10144 table: WATCHLISTPROVIDER
```

Comment: Does the new DbWatchlistProvider instance have its primary key assigned before you set it to the DbWatchlist instance and merge it?

Comment: Yes the key is set

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue, and recently found out the base cause.

In my case, the problem was that I had two `@Entity` classes referencing the same `@Table(name = X)`

When you have such a thing happening, you have to update both entities at the same time, or else you get errors like you're seeing here.

The solution (in my case) is to use a DTO Projection instead of having a duplicate entity for the one table.

Simple fix, but the error causes *way* more confusion than clarity.

No idea if you've got the same problem or not, but you do have the same error.

HTH!